# Easily check time in Yosemite full screen mode

Tags: macos, fullscreen, time

I'm trying to embrace Yosemite's full screen by default. Mostly I'm getting used to and liking it... except for the fact that without a menu bar I can't check the time at a glance.

What are some easy ways to display the current time on Yosemite without using the mouse/trackpad?

Answer (score 1):

You can move focus to menu bar with for example: <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

Alternatively You can show **Dashboard** with clock as a widget (but set the **Dashboard** not as a separate space).